Using Entra authentication with a group as the admin fails
I'm trying to connect to an Azure Sql Server resource using Entra authentication only (not mixed). I have an Entra group for my project with the team members who can function as admins on the sql server. I am an owner in the group. I set that group to the Entra Admin of the Sql Server resource.
When I try to connect through SSMS with Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA authentication I can an error
Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

If instead I set myself (just an individual user) to the admin I can log in fine.
Why does being part of a group prevent me from being able to login?
